# Using a variable with getUrl()?

Tags: image-transforms

I'd like to be able to use a variable with the getUrl() method so I can change the filter parameter on the entry page (user controlled) instead of in the source code:

`style="background-image = url('{{ getUrl(var) }}')"`

I've been trying various approaches to accomplish this: nested output tags and concatenating strings eg:

`{% set myFormat = entry.format %}
{% set myImageUrlString = "url('{{ myImage.getUrl('" ~ myFormat ~ "') }}')" %}`


...which works in part by outputting the correct string but does not get parsed (duh me!).

Can someone set me straight on the right approach to this and/or let me know whether this is even possible? TIA

July 4th, More details...

I am using a Matrix field to create a customizable grid of images. The 'format' block type is a dropdown list that contains labels/values identical to the image transforms I've created in the CP. The source code I'm using to make this work is as follows:

```
{% for myBlock in product.imageMatrix.all() %}
    {% set myImage = myBlock.image.one %}
    {% if myBlock.format == "square" %}{% set myTrans = 'square' %}{% endif %}
    {% if myBlock.format == "portrait" %}{% set myTrans = 'portrait' %}{% endif %}
    {% if myBlock.format == "landscape" %}{% set myTrans = 'landscape' %}{% endif %}
    {% set myImageUrl = myImage.getUrl(myTrans) %}
    <div class="cell image-pane-bg" style="background-image: url('{{ myImageUrl }}');"></div>   
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't very elegant but it works. Using myBlock.format as the parameter does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

When you're querying or setting a variable with a [Dropdown field](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dropdown-fields.html#querying-elements-with-dropdown-fields) you need to use either `.value` or `.label`.

It looks like you could also simplify your code a bit if the `value` (or label) of the dropdown is the same as your transform:

```
{% for myBlock in product.imageMatrix.all() %}
    {% set myImage = myBlock.image.one %}
    {% set myTrans = myBlock.format.value %}
    {% set myImageUrl = myImage.getUrl(myTrans) %}
    <div class="cell image-pane-bg" style="background-image: url('{{ myImageUrl }}');"></div>   
{% endfor %}
```

If you wanted to get even shorter (but less readable):

```
{% for myBlock in product.imageMatrix.all() %}
    <div class="cell image-pane-bg" style="background-image: url('{{ myBlock.image.one.getUrl(myBlock.format.value) }}');"></div>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't get either of these approaches to work. It's throwing an 'unknown property: label' error. The parameter in the getUrl() method has to be wrapped in single quotes as per the docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html#defining-transforms-from-the-control-panel). Could it be this is getting tripped-up by this?

Comment: @Britchie it might help to post more of your code?   What sort of field is ``format``?  Is ``myImage`` a variable you've defined or a placeholder for something else? The docs are using a single quote around the transform because that's just convention, if you use a variable you don't need quotes. My guess is you have a Twig syntax error somewhere, you just need to find out where.

Comment: Thx @RitterKnight. I've added some more details in my original post (above). It seems to be getting tripped-up on parsing the parameter from the dropdown list as a string.

Comment: @Britchie - You're close. I've updated my code above, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Working now I'm using the correct syntax. Thx for all your help @RitterKnight.

Comment: @Britchie: excellent, glad it worked!